# Contiguous-substring operator

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, notation

If string concatenation $ab$ is like left- and right-multiplication, is there any infix (latex) operator notation I can use for checking for contiguous substrings, like $bc \subseteq abcd$? $\subseteq$ doesn't seem right because it's usually about unordered sets.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) lists no standard notation. You can just invent one if you feel the need. Be sure to explain it to the reader.